# Camera doesn't capture anythin in AirSim

Tags: unreal-engine4, airsim

in my code i have the following line

```
imgs = client.simGetImages([
            airsim.ImageRequest("0", airsim.ImageType.Scene, False, False)], vehicle_name = name)
```

imgs doesn't contain anything. Do we need to enable some camera in AirSim ? I am using Unreal Engine 4. Please help me out as very less documentation is available on the web regarding airsim

Comment: Does pressing 1, 2, or 3 inside the game show the subwindows with the images?

Answer (score 0):

Did you modify the setting file to give specific description about the camera?

Or did you hit the button to run the simulation?

Comment: I first hit play in unreal engine. After that I run the code from spyder(Python IDE).